# R rename multiple columns based on partial string match - pipe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset where the column names are survey questions and are extensive, sometimes containing different punctuation from panel to panel. As such, I would like to rename all column titles that are a partial string match to a more sensible var name.

My current attempt was:

```
df %>%
  select_all(~str_replace(., "How would you describe your gender?", "cnt_gender"))
```

However, this only replaces the exact string match and leaves any others. For example:

```
Target string: "How would you describe your gender? (Select only one option)"

df %>%
  select_all(~str_replace(., "How would you describe your gender?", "cnt_gender"))

Desired output string: "cnt_gender"
Actual output string: "cnt_gender (Select only one option)"
```

What I am looking for is to completely rename the columns based on a partial string match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.*` after the string you want to replace to capture anything else that might be lurking beyond (including nothing).

```
Target_strings <- c("How would you describe your gender? (Select only one option)", 
                    "How would you describe your gender?")
str_replace(Target_strings, "How would you describe your gender?.*", "cnt_gender")
# [1] "cnt_gender" "cnt_gender"
```